# CSS arrow : How can I center a text?

Tags: html, css

Please look at http://jsfiddle.net/yusaku/NqLuX/1/

I could display an arrow by using only CSS but I could never center a text (In this example , "abc") in the TD. Doing "text-align: center" seems to be unavailable.. Could anybody suggest me ? (It is OK, the position is not COMPLETELY center)

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="arrow_td">
        <span class="name">abc</span>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>​


td.arrow_td {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
td span.name {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
td div.arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
    line-height: 0%;
    border: none;
    border-left: 20px solid black;
    border-bottom: 20px solid white;
    border-top: 20px solid white;
    border-image: initial;
}​
```

Answer (score 6):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/2uTEs/

I removed all the unnecessary elements, leaving only the necessities.

Answer (score 2):

Minimum changes

http://jsfiddle.net/NqLuX/28/

Answer (score 1):

Dirty way to do it: add right padding

```
td span.name {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-right: 70px;
}
```

this obviously will work differently with different lengths of text.